# How can I make this with Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, random

How can I make this using javascript or jquery?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IXER.jpg)

The thing i want to do is create a figure (triangle) and make a tile with this figure like the one in the image with random colors

I have tried this

```html
    <html><head>
    <style>
        body{ background-color: ivory; padding:10px; }
        #canvas{border:1px solid red;}
    </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="1000"></canvas>
                           <script type="text/javascript">

        var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

        var cw=canvas.width;
        var ch=canvas.height;

        var colwidth=cw/20;
        var rowheight=ch/20;

        for(var y=0;y<20;y++){

        for(var x=0;x<20;x++){
      
        ctx.fillStyle=randomColor();
        ctx.fillRect(x*colwidth,y*rowheight,colwidth,rowheight);
        ctx.strokeRect(x*colwidth,y*rowheight,colwidth,rowheight);
         }}

        function randomColor(){ 
        return('#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*12345678).toString(16));
        }
    </script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: What have you tried? SO can't write your code for you, but we can help you when you get stuck.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: I updated the question, there is a code but i only make tiles with cubes, i am stuck in how to make the same thing but with triangles...

Comment: Try `beginPath()`, `lineTo(x, y)`, `moveTo(x, y)` and `fill()` functions on a 2d canvas context. With these functions you should be able to draw a triangle and fill it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it with html/css only, depends how much browser support you need.

HTML

`<div class="square">
    <div class="triangle-left"></div>
    <div class="triangle-right"></div>
</div>`

CSS

`.triangle-right{
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 100px solid transparent;
    border-right: 0 solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
}
.triangle-left{
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left: 0 solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid green;
}
.square{
    position:relative;
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}`